# how to make teamcity display txt files in browser instad of download

Tags: teamcity, cicd

In teamcity version (2021), any text links would open in the browser which was good because you could save logs as txt artifacts and link to them.  Now with the latest update of teamcity (2023), any links to `.txt` artifacts, downloads the files rather than opening them in the browser.

Is there a way to force `txt` artifacts to open in browser instead of downloading?